# Invert signal from optical transceiver

Tags: transceiver, fiber

I want to achieve electrically HIGH state in this receiver (Vo tag), when there is HIGH state in the fiber. What I get now is 5 V when there is no pulse in the fiber and 0.48 V when there is (RXVCC=5 V). I can't understand why the manufacturer decide to make the electrical signal as inverse function of the optical signal. I made a PCB and I can't figure out how to do this without adding components.

https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-0176EN

[image]

Comment: Add a simple output inverter or choose an optical interface that does what you want.

Comment: There is no way to do it without adding components. Use an inverter. Many things with open collector outputs are active low.

Comment: _"I can't understand why the manufacturer decide to make the electrical signal as inverse function"_ It's cheaper to make it with open collector output = inverted output.

Comment: Just put an inverter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why inverted output?

### 1.Convenience  for HV CMOS > 5V

The datasheet says "The absence of an
internal pull-up resistor allows the open-collector output to be used with logic families such as CMOS requiring voltage excursions
much higher than VCC"

But if using a long cable or load C greater than specified for Tr, Tf  the negative leading edge will be faster from lower Rce.

### 2.Because the input is inverted

Now you must learn how to implement a TTL, CMOS or discrete inverter with cuts and jumpers, very tiny and neat.

[image]

Falstad [SIM](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCMB0BMCsBTAtADnNSkDM3IBZV95swA2M1WM7EeCeEQulLAKADc6B2MpsBrxC4%20EWCAQCpEmRDDR4bAE51Y6Uvh58N4KKgFsALiG6wIO7vHE6IkDGRxXcATljPIa%20K-vdn9IvqwsKZkzpqQEAAmiABmAIYArgA2hmwA7iZWEvgQZKbZcmw53FrCYJpkYOrlUGwA5iB51th8TcJZhSqW4sHi3QW6kPRsAEp03pBCXuKQlboQOXTzGIoZbTqU1Zqw6SZmZRWoW%20C7-b17Yvlgp1nnZ0cnDfBCOYJ8%20LO6Ow392Pu-LXmo0yPUWZ1gmjk-GE0FoUPkihUbQhuXyNjolWUFwk%20VM5hqDEq1zGVmOpIkDyhi2wsOWCN2qD%20FPQ93Q1wA9oNBkFnAsMFI7GJdNg2Jy7IL%20M50Ix5AIhmQEF8oMJRSB0BLsLx8DM4DLMINVerBrxsKhRNA8n4qoQwEFTNwiPy5crIKqZo0oCazTCgtRsPAA5B3FYA%20aBTJXUA)